# Posting questions and answers from my blog

Tags: discussion, cross-posting

My day job is teaching Hardware Description Languages. But I run what is called a fiddle www.edaplayground.com for my employer. As part of that, I have started writing a blog, the theme of which is answers to questions customers have asked me in class which I didn't know the answer to. (Sorry - that's life.)

What's the connection with EDA Playground? Well, to find out the answer, I often write a few lines of code and run them on EDA Playground. Writing up the questions and answers as a blog (well Facebook posts now) seemed like a good idea, so I've been doing that for a few months now.

Now, it occurs to me that there is a store here of good questions and (you never know) good answers. And hence posting them here (with the chit chat removed) might be of benefit to the industry. So, my question is: should I be doing that?

Why do I even ask? Well, I don't want to commit some kind of faux pas leading to all sorts of anger. And, given there are executable examples to many of the answers, I would be posting links to those (as well as putting the full code on Stack Overflow, of course). Obviously, I'd check I wasn't posting a duplicate (but, as these are questions that I didn't know the answer to, they're probably not).

Comment: If they're not duplicates and both the questions and answers follow the guidelines of Stack Overflow, they're a welcome addition to the site. Given that your blog isn't linked, we have no way of making that evaluation for you though. I suppose that was intentional so you wouldn't be accused of promoting your site.

Comment: Really interesting. I'd also be inclined to believe that would be mostly ok, especially if the rate at which questions and answers are added to the site is not overwhelming, sudden influx of posts from single source often get all sorts of scrutiny and/or drama.

Comment: The main thing is 1. They need to be non-duplicates (I would use Google to make sure) 2. You need to disclose it's your blog. Beyond that, this would be perfectly fine

Comment: *[OP takes advise, posts question and answer, massively downvoted, voted as off topic, closed, deleted, "we are no longer taking questions from this account"]*

Comment: Honestly, while if you do what Machavity says it might not strictly be against the rules, you risk people frowning upon it, examining your questions with a fine tooth comb, and finding another reason to close/downvote/delete it (thus what Will said could pretty likely happen).

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm a big fan of this. Remember [what Stack Overflow was originally conceived as](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHX9P.png)--we're that asterisk right in the center. As long as you phrase your question in the form of a question, [following our standard format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), and provide *unique*, *useful* information, then your contributions will be welcome here. If such contributions are not welcomed, please let me know, as some re-education is necessary.